# How to scan a string and write it in a file?

Tags: c, string

I want to scan a string that a user inputs, then write it into the file (file.txt), but this doesn't seem to work for some reason

```
int main()
{
    FILE *stream;

    stream = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    char str[] = { '\0 ' };
    scanf("%s", &str);
    fprintf(stream, "%s.\n", str);


    fclose(stream);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How long is `str`?

Comment: How much does `scanf("%s"..` read?

Comment: 20 characters at most

Comment: Is `str` long enough? Does `scanf` prevent more than 20 characters to be read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, should work just fine.
It did for me so it should for you too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *stream;

stream = fopen("ceva.txt", "w");
if (stream == NULL) {
   perror("Failed: ");
   return 1;
}
char str[250];
scanf("%249s", str);
fprintf(stream, "%s.\n", str);


fclose(stream);

return 0;}
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", str);` to `scanf("%249s", str);`

Comment: Yes, thank you, guys. I just did it to present a code that works for the purpose of printing into a file something read from the keyboard. I just rushed in and forgot. Thanks again

Comment: Perhaps also check `stream` is not null as well

Comment: Robust code always checks the return value of input functions.  `if (scanf("%249s", str) == 1) fprintf(stream, "%s.\n", str);`

Comment: In most cases scanf("%s",...) is not what most users want to use since scanf("%s") just reads words terminated by whitespace, which is quite confusing in many situations, e.g. pressing ENTER does not make it return since ENTER is whitespace. In many cases you are better off with using fgets().

Answer (score 0):

You must change `scanf` with `fscanf`